# How to populate ejs form dropdown list options from MySQL database?

Tags: html, mysql, forms, ejs

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Station_Type">Station Type</label>
                <select name="Station_Type" class="form-control" name="Station_Type" id="Station_Type" autocomplete="off">
                
                    <option>Sewing</option>
                    <option>Cutting</option>
                    <option>Finishing</option>
                    <option>Distribution</option>
                    <option>Ironing</option>
                    <option>Offline</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

I want the option values of this dropdown field to be populated by values stored in a separate table named 'stationoptions' in MySQL database which will be constantly updated. Right now, the options are hardcoded as shown in my code above, however, I want the dropdown list to be automatically updated whenever new values are added to the 'stationoptions' table in MySQL. May I know how do I query the data from MySQL to this form field?

This is how I insert the data from this form into another separate table. (in my .js file)

```
addPlayerPage: (req, res) => {
    res.render('add-player.ejs', {
        title: "Welcome | Add a new transaction",
        message: ''
    });
},

addPlayer: (req, res) => {
    
    let playerId = req.params.id;
    let LineNo = req.body.LineNo;
    let Station_Type = req.body.Station_Type;

   
    let query = "INSERT INTO `lineid` (id, LineNo, Station_Type) VALUES (NULL, '" + LineNo + "', '" + Station_Type + "')"; 


            db.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }                
        
            });  
            res.redirect('/line'); 
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="Station_Type">Station Type</label>
   <select id="Station_Type" name="Station_Type" class="form-control" placeholder="Station_Type" value="<%= playerLine.Station_Type %>" required>

<!-- for loop code start -->
   <% for(var i=0; i < playerLine.length; i++) { %>
   <option value="<%= playerLine[i].Station_Type %>"><%= playerLine[i].Station_Type %></option>
   <% } %>
<!-- for loop code end -->

<!-- and maybe you can remove this part -->
<option value="<%= playerLine.Station_Type %>"><%= playerLine.Station_Type %></option>
                    <option>Sewing</option>
                    <option>Cutting</option>
                    <option>Finishing</option>
                    <option>Distribution</option>
                    <option>Ironing</option>
                    <option>Offline</option>
<!-- and maybe you can remove this part -->

     </select>
 </div>
```

**EDIT**

In your `js` file:

```
addPlayerPage: (req, res) => {
    // query the table you want show in your ejs
    let myQuery = "SELECT field_name FROM table_name;" // query for the dropdown

    db.query(myQuery , function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err); // check if query have error
            }
            res.render('add-player.ejs', {
                title: "Welcome | Add a new transaction",
                message: '',
                drecord: result // setting result reference for ejs
            });
        })
},

addPlayer: (req, res) => {
    
    let playerId = req.params.id;
    let LineNo = req.body.LineNo;
    let Station_Type = req.body.Station_Type;

   
    let query = "INSERT INTO `lineid` (id, LineNo, Station_Type) VALUES (NULL, '" + LineNo + "', '" + Station_Type + "')"; 


            db.query(query, (err, result) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }                
        
            });  
            res.redirect('/line'); 
},
```

In you `add-player.ejs`:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="Station_Type">Station Type</label>
   <select id="Station_Type" name="Station_Type" class="form-control" placeholder="Station_Type" required>

<!-- for loop code start -->
   <% for(var i=0; i < drecord.length; i++) { %>
   <option value="<%= drecord[i].field_name %>"><%= drecord[i].field_name %></option>
   <% } %>
<!-- for loop code end -->

     </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: But how do I make the query from MySQL?

Comment: The query in MySQL is just straight forward like `SELECT field_name FROM table_name` only. What I'm interested to know is are you able to show something in the ejs that is coming from any MySQL query result? If not, you probably have to include more information in your question like the backend code (js), the routing info and db connection code especially `multipleStatements: true` enabled

Comment: Where should I insert the MySQL query statement in my code? I have included more information in my question. I hope it helps! Thank you

Comment: Yes it works, thank you! Is it possible for the dropdown to be populated with only a selected few values based on what the user selects from another form field in the same form? For example, if the user selects '1' for the LineNo field, only options 'cutting' and 'sewing' will be populated in the Station_Type dropdown. If the user selects '2' for the LineNo field, only options 'finishing' and 'distribution' will be populated in the Station_Type dropdown. Thanks!

Comment: I can think of at least two ways. One is to have multiple query in the backend but if the selection are a lot; lets say a range 1 to 20, you might end up writing 20 queries or 1 very long query. The second way is to leave the backend as it is and modify the front end instead; adding javascript in the ejs to populate the dropdown list. I don't have any extensive experience in doing such method though so I'm just giving a theoretic ideas. I'm guessing to try and achieve that will take a lot of testing. But if your selection is less than 5, you could try the first method.

Comment: Come to think of it, if you need the second dropdown list to change in reference from another dropdown list, the first idea I gave in my comment above might not work.

Comment: If my second dropdown list will be in a separate form, will the first idea work? If it does how do I execute the query?

Comment: I think it can but you need to post the first dropdown list then only populate (or show) the second dropdown list based on the first dropdown selection. I would suggest you post a new question with new title and description of what you're trying to achieve. Don't forget to include the codes that you're working with. That way you can attract more people to help you. I have a general idea how it would work but I'm also quite a beginner in this. It's just coincidence that what you're asking is something I have been working with for a while.